# Malware on CPanel Shared Server

Tags: server, cpanel

I've a shared hosting plan. Some malware viruses get infected whole server. It creates folders, files automatically. I can not find the file which is affecting all these events.

I use cPanel.

Google Search Console see this as social engineering.

My hosting plan doesn't allow me to connect to server via SSH. So I can not install any antivirus or malware scanner.

Is there anyone who has a idea what can I do for this situation?

Comment: You will need to contact the hosting company and get them to fix this.  Or cancel your service and move to a better company or possibly Amazon Lightsail. (If you can live with only 3 mailboxes, there is a free Plesk image for Lightsail and servers start at $5/month.)  Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault.com not here.

Comment: Can I find the file that occurs this? There are so many websites on this hosting.

Comment: Plesk on Amazon Lightsail (there are also videos on YouTube, search "plesk lightsail") - https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/deployment-guide/plesk-installation-and-upgrade-on-public-cloud-services/installing-plesk-on-amazon-lightsail.79028/

Comment: I've paid for reseller hosting account. I'd like to find the bug and fix it

Comment: Your hosting company can help you deal with infections and patches needed to prevent them.